# nginx leaks my hidden service port number

Tags: onion-services, information-leaks

I have my .onion service running:

http://oeptyn6jtusgda63.onion/

When i try to open wrong link, my TorBrowser shows me an error like this:

Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at oeptyn6jtusgda63.onion:**7541**.

Is there some way i can prevent nginx to leak my server port number?

I have learned myself, that nginx first send redirection (http code 301) that leaks my port number. Is there some way i can disable it?

**UPD** :

This happens when i try to access some directory, like this:

http://oeptyn6jtusgda63.onion/zip

Comment: I experiment the same issue but this solution not working for me. I've try the solution in nginx.conf file and also in the website config file `/etc/nginx/site-available/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it myself. I just added this directive to `nginx.conf` :

```
port_in_redirect off;
```

This directive briefly described in nginx doc: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#port_in_redirect

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution. Can you accept your own answer so this question can be closed?